# GC.Collect and multithreading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using C# 3.5 and the reactive extension supporting TPL in C# version before 4.

My application calls GC.Collect() in several places (yes, I know that I should not manually call this method but please leave this point alone for at least this question). Before I put multithreading implementation in, it works fine. GC.Collect() is called in each of the thread so it is called in a multithreading context.

Then I use the Task to implement multithreading and I found that after the application running for a while and the memory usage increases, the threads stop working properly. I declare "the threads stop working properly" from the scenario that the CPU usage on a multi-core computer drops to single-thread level, rather than fully utilized.

When I attempted to tackle this problem, the only thing I did was to comment out the GC.Collect() call and this change makes the threads working fine. I would like to turn GC.Collect() off unless when I run something big in my application, without GC.Collect(), I will run into OutOfMemory exception. This is the reason I keep the call.

Now could anyone explain why GC.Collect() being called in a multithreading context on a machine using high memory causes multithreading problem? Is there any related theory on this bit? Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GC.Collect()` performs a *full* garbage collection which will block all threads.  It has an overload `GC.Collect(int)` that allows you to specify which generations to collect.  For example, `GC.Collect(0)` will only collect the first generation.  Not certain that will solve your problem, but worth a shot.

Comment: What a quick and insightful help. I will have a try. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As [Kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732053/gc-collect-and-multithreading-in-c/3732082#3732082) has said, a collection pauses all threads. This might result in some latency during garbage collection.

If you are running your application on a multi-core machine, you might want to try using the Server GC, by making sure that your app.config contains:

```
<configuration>
 <runtime>
   <gcServer enabled="true"/>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Also one can enable concurrent GC instead (though I think this is the default for your case, e.g. a desktop app on a multi-core machine, running .NET 3.5):

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You might try ServerGC - it might give pauses as well, but these pauses may be shorter/fewer and it might give a better overall throughput. 
Your mileage may vary.